# scoll in select option disabled after using jqtransform

Tags: jqtransform

I have a problem with Jqtransform , when it transform the select input , it disable scrolling on the option value and make it appear very long drop down selection 
like in the image i attached ![enter image description here][1]
i need help please 
Thanks

http://imm.io/pi0d

Answer (score 3):

jquery.jqtransform.js

add this code -> **.css('height', 120)**

line=265

looks like

> var $ul = $('ul',
>   $wrapper).css('width',$select.width())**.css('height', 120)**.hide();

Answer (score 0):

Rather than giving height to it I would suggest give it an **overflow-y:scroll**

var $ul = $('ul', $wrapper).css('width',$select.width()).css('overflow-y', 'scroll').hide();

Let the height be given through CSS and not through JS...

Hope this helps :)